# JavaScript Regular Expression Can't get a matched group

Tags: javascript, regex, grouping

I'm trying to use JavaScript regular expression with the exec function and hoping to get matches for a group. I just can't figure out why I'm getting no matches.

Here is my code:

```
var elementClass="validate[required]"
var myRegexp = /validate\\[(*)\\]/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(elementClass);
```

match is null every time. I can't figure out why. It should be getting "required".

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Java != JavaScript.  I changed the title to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
var myRegexp = /validate\[(.*)\]/;
```

First of all you only need one backslash to escape - otherwise you're searching for a literal backslash followed by the special meaning of what you were trying to escape.

Second, `*` just means "zero or more of the last thing", which in this case makes no sense because there is nothing there. `.` means "anything" (well, almost) so `.*` means "any number of anythings".

Finally, the `g` flag is unnecessary here, especially if you're trying to capture a part of the result.

Comment: Ok that works but one thing I'm noticing is I keep getting 2 results. So match has 2 elements. The first element is always just exactly what was put in, and the second is the part between the brackets, in this case required.

Comment: That's how regexes work. The first element of the match array is always the full match, then each subsequent entry corresponds to the next subpattern (in this case, the `disabled` string)

Answer (score 2):

1) You have to many slashes

```
var myRegexp = /validate\[(.*?)\]/g;
```

2) If you want to match the part in square brackets only, you should use groups

```
var result = match[1];
```

Comment: Doesn't anyone bother testing their code before using it in an answer?

Comment: @Kolink can't check it right now, but don't see any reason for why it's null

Comment: Just hit F12, instant JavaScript console. See my answer for why yours won't work.

Comment: @Kolink for some reason either my nor your regex are working, should I downvote your too? http://gyazo.com/baeb57eb55676f6257222de3f83ef036

Comment: Your use of the console is incorrect, you aren't returning anything for the console to display.

Comment: @Kolink than you have to look better, because my last edit works just fine on alert(match[1]) and my last edit was before your answer

Comment: You are indeed correct. My apologies. I've become so accustomed to using `String.match` rather than `RegExp.exec` that I had forgotten how `g` works differently in the latter case. Downvote removed, upvote added.